# Update model from filter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a list of form names and a list of forms. When a user clicks on a form name I want to only show forms that match the name that was clicked. I am passing the form name on click but I can't figure out how to update the list of forms shown based on that. How do you update the model in a filter?

JS

```
App.PatientFormsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  actions:
    filterForms: (name)->
      @get('model').filterBy('name', name)
```

HTML

```
<h2>Form Types</h2>
<div id='form-names'>
  <ul>
    {{#each formTypes}}
      <li>
        <a href="*" {{action 'filterForms' name on='click'}}>{{nameFormatted}}</a>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>

<h2>Forms</h2>
<div id="patient-forms">
  {{#each}}
    <b>{{name}}</b><br />
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with the following:

JS

```
App.PatientFormsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  init: -> @set 'filteredForms', @get('model')
  actions:
    filterForms: (name)->
      @set 'filteredForms', @get('model').filterBy('name', name)
```

HTML

```
<h2>Form Types</h2>
<div id='form-names'>
  <ul>
    {{#each formTypes}}
      <li>
        <a href="*" {{action 'filterForms' name on='click'}}>{{nameFormatted}}</a>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>

<h2>Forms</h2>
<div id="patient-forms">
  {{#each filteredForms}}
    <b>{{name}}</b><br />
  {{/each}}
</div>
```